# How to find a word NOT inside <a> tag?

Tags: ruby, regex

I need help with regular expressions. My task is very simular to twitter's hashtags: I have a string with words staring with `#`. For example:

```
foo #bar hello
```

I'm replacing hashtags with links before it saved into database and get strings like this:

```
foo <a href="bar">#bar</a>
```

After that sometimes I need to re-parse string and I don't want to replace `#bar` inside the `<a>` tag twice. I need regexp that should find a word beginning with `#` and placed NOT inside `>`, `<`, `>` and `</a>`.

Comment: is this `foo <a href="bar">#bar</a>` your expected output?

Comment: Will the `#bar` only be one level deep? because I think I have a solution provided these are not nested within any other tags.

Comment: And of course there is the classic question, have you considered an xml parser?

Comment: To manipulate HTML you should really have a look at Nokogiri gem: http://nokogiri.org

Comment: Having to reparse the string make me think you didn't work out your logic well. Figure out all the changes to the string prior to modifying it so you only do it once, otherwise you'll paint yourself into corners.

Answer (score 0):

To get from your input:

```
foo #bar hello
```

to your output:

```
foo <a href="bar">#bar</a> hello
```

idempotently, so you can pass your output back through your function and it will not change, you could use this:

```
str1 = "foo #bar hello"
str2 = 'foo <a href="bar">#bar</a> hello'
replace_func = -> str { str.sub(/#(\w+)(?=[^<]*?(?:<[^\/]|$))/, '<a href="\1">#\1</a>')}
replace_func[str1]
replace_func[str2]
# both return: "foo <a href=\"bar\">#bar</a> hello"
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eP5kA4)

Additionally Nokogiri can be used very simply:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML('<p>' + you_string + '</p>')
doc.search('//p').each do |node|
  node.content = node.content.sub(/#\w+/)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage with Nokogiri is that you can easily check with an XPath query if a text node doesn't have a link node as ancestor *(links can't be nested)* and if it contains at least one `#` *(it's useless to search inside  other text nodes)*:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_doc)

doc.search('//text()[not(ancestor::a) and contains(., "#")]').each do |txt|
    txt.content.split(/(#\w+)/).each_with_index do |v, k|
        if k%2 > 0
            node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new("a", doc)
            node.content = v
            node['href'] = "http://domain.com?usr=" + v[1..-1]
        else
            node = v
        end
        txt.before(node)
    end
    txt.remove
end

puts doc.to_html
```

or more simple:

```
doc.search('//text()[not(ancestor::a) and contains(., "#")]').each do |txt|
    txt.content.split(/(#\w+)/).each_with_index do |v, k|
        if k%2 > 0
            v = '<a href="http://domain.com?usr=' + v[1..-1] + '">' + v + '</a>'
        end
        txt.before(v)
    end
    txt.remove
end
```

Note: if you need to deal with only parts of a complete html document, you must make little changes to make it works *(You need to wrap the html in a root node, to make the XPath query work)*:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::fragment('<div>' + html_doc + '</div>')
doc.search('.//text()[not(ancestor::a) and contains(., "#")]').each do |txt|

    txt.content.split(/(#\w+)/).each_with_index do |v, k|
        if k%2 > 0
            v = "<a href=\"http://mydomain.com?usr=#{v[1..-1]}\">#{v}</a>"
        end
        txt.before(v)
    end
    txt.remove
end
doc.xpath('*/node()').each do |node|
    puts node.to_html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
/\<[^>]+\>[^<]*(\#[a-zA-Z]+)/
```

[a-zA-Z] are letters that could be in the word after #. you can use this if you want to numbers also be included:

```
/\<[^>]+\>[^<]*(\#[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/
```